# Using regular expressions to find a word with the five letters abcde, each letter appearing exactly once, in any order, with no breaks in between

Tags: regex, perl

For example, the word *debacle* would work because of **debac**, but *seabed* would not work because: 1. there is no c in any 5-character sequence that can be formed, and 2. the letter e appears twice. As another example, *feedback* would work because of **edbac**. And remember, the solution must be done using only regular expressions.

A strategy I attempted to implement was: match the first letter if it's inside [a-e], and remember it. Then find the next letter in [a-e] but not the first letter. And so on. I wasn't sure what the syntax was (or even if some syntax existed) so my code didn't work:

```
open(DICT, "dictionary.txt");
@words = <DICT>;

foreach my $word(@words){

if ($word =~ /([a-e])([a-e^\1])([a-e^\1^\2])([a-e^\1^\2^\3])([a-e^\1^\2^\3^\4])/
){
    print $word;
}
}
```

I was also thinking of using (?=regex) and \G but I wasn't sure how it would work out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/
   (?= .{0,4}a )
   (?= .{0,4}b )
   (?= .{0,4}c )
   (?= .{0,4}d )
   (?= .{0,4}e )
/xs
```

---

It's probably results in faster matching to generate a pattern from all combinations.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NextPermute );
my @pats;
my @chars = 'a'..'e';
do { push @pats, quotemeta join '', @chars; } while NextPermute(@chars);
my $re = join '|', @pats;
```

abcde|abced|abdce|abdec|abecd|abedc|acbde|acbed|acdbe|acdeb|acebd|acedb|adbce|adbec|adcbe|adceb|adebc|adecb|aebcd|aebdc|aecbd|aecdb|aedbc|aedcb|bacde|baced|badce|badec|baecd|baedc|bcade|bcaed|bcdae|bcdea|bcead|bceda|bdace|bdaec|bdcae|bdcea|bdeac|bdeca|beacd|beadc|becad|becda|bedac|bedca|cabde|cabed|cadbe|cadeb|caebd|caedb|cbade|cbaed|cbdae|cbdea|cbead|cbeda|cdabe|cdaeb|cdbae|cdbea|cdeab|cdeba|ceabd|ceadb|cebad|cebda|cedab|cedba|dabce|dabec|dacbe|daceb|daebc|daecb|dbace|dbaec|dbcae|dbcea|dbeac|dbeca|dcabe|dcaeb|dcbae|dcbea|dceab|dceba|deabc|deacb|debac|debca|decab|decba|eabcd|eabdc|eacbd|eacdb|eadbc|eadcb|ebacd|ebadc|ebcad|ebcda|ebdac|ebdca|ecabd|ecadb|ecbad|ecbda|ecdab|ecdba|edabc|edacb|edbac|edbca|edcab|edcba

(This will get optimised into a trie in Perl 5.10+. Before 5.10, use Regexp::List.)

Comment: +1 - I like this better than my own solution.  To explain for others, the lookaheads guarantee that: in the next 5 letters, there's at least one 'a', at least one 'b', at least one 'c', at least one 'd', and at least one 'e'.  Given that there are only five "slots," it's guaranteed that each appear exactly once.

Comment: Alternative solution also works if you want to find stuff with duplicate (e.g. abcdd instead of abcde)

Comment: That was a tidy solution, +1

Answer (score 7):

Your solution is clever but unfortunately `[a-e^...]` doesn't work, as you found.  I don't believe there is a way to mix regular and negated character classes.  I can think of a workaround using lookaheads though:

```
    /(([a-e])(?!\2)([a-e])(?!\2)(?!\3)([a-e])(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4])([a-e])(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4])(?!\5)([a-e]))/
```

See it here: http://rubular.com/r/6pFrJe78b6.

**UPDATE:** Mob points out in the comments below, that alternation can be used to compact the above:

```
    /(([a-e])(?!\2)([a-e])(?!\2|\3)([a-e])(?!\2|\3|\4])([a-e])(?!\2|\3|\4|\5)([a-e]))/
```

The new demo: http://rubular.com/r/UUS7mrz6Ze.

Comment: Note that you cannot have backreferences within character classes.  Hence the need for multiple backreferences instead of something like ``(?![\2\3\4\5])``.  Also, I had to start counting at 2 not 1 because I wanted to include an "overall" capture group for the rubular demo.

Comment: But you can use alternation: `...(?!\2|\3|\4|\5)`

Answer (score 6):

```
#! perl -lw
for (qw(debacle seabed feedback)) {
    print if /([a-e])(?!\1)
        ([a-e])(?!\1)(?!\2)
        ([a-e])(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)
        ([a-e])(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4)
        ([a-e])/x;
}
```